# does vuex mapState always require module name as argument even if namespaced:false

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I was expecting that if I have a module that has `namespaced:false` (which I think is also the default) then its **state** should be part of the "global" or "root" namespace and that I would be able to do " `...mapState('someStateAttribute')` and then refer to `someStateAttribute` but it would seem that I must use `...mapState('modulename','someStateAttribute')` or else it does not work.

Is this just the case? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`mapState`'s signature](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html):

```
mapState(namespace?: string, map: Array<string> | Object<string | function>): Object
```

This means the first argument, `namespace`, is optional. But if you provide a string as first argument, it will be the `namespace`.

To achieve what you want you should do:

```
...mapState(['someStateAttribute'])
```

Comment: ohhh.... so I must use an array with the mapped state name if I want to omit the namespace, otherwise my state name was interpreted as being a namespace...

Comment: Yep, that's it! Have a closer look at the sources: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/v3.0.1/dist/vuex.js#L790 as you can `mapState` uses a `normalizeNamespace` function. And in `normalizeNamespace`'s implementation, the first argument is not used as `namespace` only if it is not a string: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/v3.0.1/dist/vuex.js#L907